# keeping 2 databases updated

Tags: python, mysql

I have 2 databases, 1 in the cloud using MySQL and one local using SQLite3. The cloud one has login data for the whole system, and the local one had login data for that specific company. If I delete an entry on the cloud I want the local one to update or delete surplus entries. I can't delete all entries and start again because there are things I want to keep for each entry(eg last login time)

I have this: (c_l is the local database and l_db is the cloud)

```
            c_l.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM login")
            za = c_l.fetchall()
            for i in za:
                l_db.execute("SELECT company FROM login WHERE username = %s", [i[1]])
                z = l_db.fetchone()
                if z is None:
                    z = "not"
                if z[0] != company and i[5] != 1:
                    c_l.execute("DELETE FROM login WHERE oid = ?", [i[5]])
                    conn_login.commit()
```

It works fine and does what I want, but it's slow, with about 40 entries it can take about 5 seconds because it's checking the cloud for each entry individually. I'm sure there's a better way but I can't find it. is there a better way?

Comment: Is one the Primary server and the other the Replica?  If not, can you switch to that.

Comment: Its not quite a replica, the main cloud hold all data for all companies, I want to local on to only show the data for the company that is loged in